# Transpose sheets in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I Have 18 sheets in one excel file. I want to transpose these sheets then combine them in one sheet.
The concatenation is working for me using pd.concat but transpsose didnt work for all sheets using data.transpose()[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRdpE.png)

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward. The first thing I would check is that you have the same number of rows and columns in each dataset. If it works for some but not others you may need to add filler / dummy data into the rows and columns missing it.

Comment: yes all sheet have the same rows and columns

Comment: Are any of them zeroes or null-data? Sometimes that will cause Numpy to crap out. You might try copying / pasting a dataset that does work and a dataset that does not work into the question text.

Comment: Yes there are NoData cells

Comment: I see you're new here. I suggest that when someone comments with, "Hey, please give me all the data you can, and show a working / non-working sheet," you expand on your question to include that. It is impossible to answer this question without looking very closely and your special case. I know, because I've been working with Excel and Excel exports for decades.